# Codeigniter in select option default value not working

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Hi I am the beginner of Codeigniter. The following is my code. The issue is, it does not display the default value in select opinion menu. Please assist, Thank you.

```
<select name="taskOption1" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
    <?php
        foreach($stagesData as $key => $value):
            echo '<option value="'. $value -> stage_id . '"' .
            set_select('taskOption1', $rows[0] -> stage_reject_id) . '>' . $value -> stage_name . '</option>';
        endforeach;
     ?>
</select>
```

Comment: remove the `disabled`

Comment: This disabled is only for first option. Not concern with other option.

Comment: From the looks of it, you are trying to select multiple option, so add `multiple` in select. and `set_select`'s the third (optional) parameter lets you set an item as the default (use boolean TRUE/FALSE).

Comment: Thank you NULL I already test it, but it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you have a default option, I guess that should be the one selected? If so, you don't need `<option value="" disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>`. But I may have understood this the wrong way.

Second, if you want to set a default value with `set_select()` in CodeIgniter, you must use the third parameter, like this:

```
set_select('taskOption1', $rows[0] -> stage_reject_id, TRUE)
```

Comment: When I put TRUE in set_select method it show last value from select option. not show default value.

Comment: yes, it does, because you must insert it conditionally. Otherwise, all the options get SELECTed, and, of course, it settles to the last one.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="taskOption2" class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
        <?php
            foreach($rejectsData as $key => $value):
                echo '<option value="'. $value -> reject_id . '"' .
                set_select('taskOption2', $rows[0] -> stage_reject_id, ((($value -> reject_id) == ($rows[0] -> reject_id))?true:false)) . '>' . $value -> reject_name . '</option>';
             endforeach;
        ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Form Helper`, I see, so why don't you use `from_dropdown` or for multiple use `form_multiselect`

```
form_dropdown([$name = '', $options, $selected, $extra)
Parameters: 
$name (string) – Field name
$options (array) – An associative array of options to be listed
$selected (string) – Selected Value
$extra (mixed) – Extra attributes
```

For your code

```
<?php $stagesData = ['' => '--select--'] + $stagesData; ?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('taskOption1', $stagesData, ''); ?>
```

Comment: Thank for answer NULL, where I put form_dropdown method. In controller or view?

Comment: you have to put that in the view.